# grafanaとzabbixプラグインエラーについて

Tags: linux, zabbix, データの可視化

grafanaを入れてzabbixプラグインのインストール後に有効化し
「Data sources」でSettingsを行い正常に保存されました。
その後、「Dashboards」へ推移すると「Failed to get plugin dashboards」と表示されます。

調べてもバグのようですが、修正する方法はございますか。
grafana-cli plugins install alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app

zabbxi 6.4.2
grafana 9.5.2
AlmaLinux release 9.1